# How do I convert a list of dictionaries formatted this way to a dataframe looking like as shown below? (without hard-coding)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert data originally formatted as a list of dictionaries shown as below:

```
[{'Data': [{'VarCharValue': 'date'}, {'VarCharValue': 'clientid'}]},
 {'Data': [{'VarCharValue': '20200203'}, {'VarCharValue': '123457'}]},
 {'Data': [{'VarCharValue': '20200202'}, {'VarCharValue': '123456'}]}]
```

To a
[image]

whereby the 'date' and 'clientid' are column headers.

Would greatly appreciate if someone could help me out with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [
    {"Data": [{"VarCharValue": "date"}, {"VarCharValue": "clientid"}]},
    {"Data": [{"VarCharValue": "20200203"}, {"VarCharValue": "123457"}]},
    {"Data": [{"VarCharValue": "20200202"}, {"VarCharValue": "123456"}]},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[v["VarCharValue"] for v in d["Data"]] for d in lst[1:]],
    columns=[v["VarCharValue"] for v in lst[0]["Data"]],
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       date clientid
0  20200203   123457
1  20200202   123456
```

Answer (score 1):

- data starts at index 1,  column headers are in at index 0
- for each **column** extract *VarCharValue*
- finally rename columns based on index 0

```
mylist = [
    {"Data": [{"VarCharValue": "date"}, {"VarCharValue": "clientid"}]},
    {"Data": [{"VarCharValue": "20200203"}, {"VarCharValue": "123457"}]},
    {"Data": [{"VarCharValue": "20200202"}, {"VarCharValue": "123456"}]},
]


# data starts at index 1
pd.DataFrame(mylist[1:])["Data"].apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series([d["VarCharValue"] for d in x])
).rename(columns={i: d["VarCharValue"] for i, d in enumerate(mylist[0]["Data"])})
```

|  | date | clientid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20200203 | 123457 |
| 1 | 20200202 | 123456 |